# Why dosn't this objective-c if statement work?

Tags: iphone, ios, if-statement

I's sorry but I'm new to Xcode and coding.

Im trying to create an If statement so that if label 3 = or greater then 20 label 4 = 0, else if lower then 20 it = 1 and if lower then 18.5 its = 2.

this is my code for that:

```
    if (_label3.text >= @"20") {_label4.text = @"0";}
else if (_label3.text < @"20") {_label4.text = @"1";}
else if (_label3.text <= @"18.5") {_label4.text = @"2";}
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong, but i am getting this error 'Direct comparison of String literal has undefined behavior' and Xcode wont let me build the app.

Thank for your Help

Comment: It seems to me you've completely changed the question. Not just the code, but the error message you said you were getting as well. Please don't waste people's time posting questions just to completely change them a moment later. Take the time to review the preview that SO gives you to make sure it's correct first.

Comment: If I am not wrong, are you trying to compare the number value inside label, right? If yes, this is not the approach to take.

Comment: >= < <= is not working upon string.please convert label text in integer.then compare with integer. stackoverflow doesn't encourage this type of question.

Comment: You should be reading a basic C tutorial instead of making iOS apps already...

Comment: I'm Sorry for the edits but I noticed a silly mistake as soon as I posted, I creacted and got a new error, so I amended the posts, this is the first time I have used StackOverFlow, and didn't know what to expect, I didn't expect people to read the post within a couple of mins of posting, its my fault and I'm sorry, I am grateful for all the help everyone is giving, Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using arithmetic operations on strings. that for sure makes no sense

create a float from the textfield input

```
if ([_label3.text floatValue] >= 20.0) {_label4.text = @"0";}
```

aslo you have to change the 1st and 2nd else branch, a the last one will never be called, as if it is true, the fist one is also be true.

---

```
float value = [_label3.text floatValue];

if (value > 20.0) {_label4.text = @"0";}
else if (value  <= 18.5) {_label4.text = @"2";}
else if (value < 20.0) {_label4.text = @"1";}
```

Comment: +1 First and only answer to note the fractional value. :-)

Comment: THank you, this has worked possibly, I know understand what I was doing wrong, I have been Learning from a couple of online tutorials, and after googling for a long time, couldn't workout the answer.

Answer (score 2):

label.text is string value and you cant compare string to int. Change the string to int and then compare like this

```
if([_label3.text intValue] >= 20){
   _label4.text = @"0";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the answer is valid. What he faces is an error of comparing string in if expression.

Comment: Thank you that works, and i have copied it and made it work for the else if, but i can't get it to work with <= it comes up with Expression Result unused?

Comment: You need to do similar thing in <= condition also. Otherwise, please post current code.

Comment: +1, though, the answer points the right way, which is the important thing. But probably not `int`, some of the values are fractional.

Comment: But the question's first condition is an int value, that's why i chose int...:)